# How do i add different types of account?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello new to this php like ask how to add different account type in my sign up file where admin = 1 customer = 2 employee = 3  i don't know how to implement my code.

My sign up form

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    if(isset($_POST['susername'])){
        $username=$_POST['susername'];
        $password=$_POST['spassword'];

        $query=$conn->query("select * from user where username='$username'");

        if ($query->num_rows>0){
            ?>
                <span>Username already exist.</span>
            <?php 
        }

        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/",$username)){
            ?>
                <span style="font-size:11px;">Invalid username. Space & Special Characters not allowed.</span>
            <?php 
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/",$password)){
            ?>
                <span style="font-size:11px;">Invalid password. Space & Special Characters not allowed.</span>
            <?php 
        }
        else{
            $mpassword=md5($password);
            $conn->query("insert into user (username, password) values ('$username', '$mpassword')");
            ?>
                <span>Sign up Successful.</span>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

here my login.php for my file in creating multi user role

```
<?php 
    include('conn.php');
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        $query=$conn->query("select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'");

        if ($query->num_rows>0){
            $row=$query->fetch_array();
            $_SESSION['users']=$row['id']; 
        }
        else{
            ?>
                <span>Login Failed. User not Found.</span>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?> 
how do i add them in my code.
```

Comment: You can add a column as `user_role` in your `users` table that will carry your user role to handle users based on their role

Comment: how do put them into code i don't really know how to implement them.

Comment: You can refer to these - https://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/  , https://sevvlor.com/post/2014/10/14/how-to-make-role-based-access-control-in-php/  , http://phprbac.net/docs_tutorial.php